# Require rally rest api jar built with java 5

Tags: rally

I need rally-rest-api-1.0.2.jar which is built on JAVA 5? Does Rally provide this or do we need to build one ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Rally REST Toolkit for Java is built using Java 6.  The latest version is [1.0.4](https://github.com/downloads/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/rally-rest-api-1.0.4.jar).  I don't think that the library itself is using anything specific to 6 but I'm not sure about its libraries (Gson and HttpClient).  If you'd like to try all the source is available [here](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava).  Please let the community know how it goes.

Comment: I built the toolkit with JAVA5 and it runs fine. Thanks Kyle.